# Use dynamic (variable) string as regex pattern in dart

Tags: regex, dart, flutter

i am trying to pass variable in regex 
language DART

```
  `betweenLenth(val, field, [min = 4, max = 20]) {
     final RegExp nameExp = new RegExp(r'^\w{" + min + "," + max + "}$');
     if (!nameExp.hasMatch(val))
     return field + " must be between $min - $max characters ";
   }`
```

thanks

Comment: Should the double quotes be in the resulting rexex pattern? Can you please add how the desired result would look like?

Comment: Try `final RegExp nameExp = new RegExp(r'^\w{' + min + ',' + max + r'}$');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A generic function to **escape any literal string that you want to put inside a regex as a literal pattern part** may look like

```
escape(String s) {
  return s.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]'), (x) {return "\\${x[0]}";});
}
```

It is necessary because an unescaped special regex metacharacter either causes a regex compilation error (like mismatched `(` or `)`) or may make the pattern match something unexpected. See more details about [escaping strings for regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Escaping) at MDN.

So, if you have `myfile.png`, the output of `escape('myfile.png')` will be `myfile\.png` and the `.` will only match literal dot char now.

In the current scenario, you do not have to use this function because max and min thresholds are expressed with digits and digits are no special regex metacharacters.

You may just use

```
betweenLenth(val, field, [min = 4, max = 20]) {
     final RegExp nameExp = new RegExp("^\\w{$min,$max}\$");
     if (!nameExp.hasMatch(val))
            return field + " must be between $min - $max characters ";
     return "Correct!";
}
```

The resulting regex is `^\w{4,20}$`.

Note:

- Use non-raw string literals in order to use string interpolation
- Escape the end of string anchor in regular string literals to define a literal `$` char
- Use double backslashes to define regex escape sequences (`"\\d"` to match digits, etc.)

Answer (score 24):

You can't use string-interpolation with raw strings.

With interpolation

```
final RegExp nameExp = new RegExp('^\\w{"$min","$max"}\$');
final RegExp nameExp = new RegExp('^\\w{$min,$max}\$');
```

with concatenation

```
final RegExp nameExp = new RegExp(r'^\w{"' + min + '","' + max + r'"}$');
final RegExp nameExp = new RegExp(r'^\w{' + min + ',' + max + r'}$');
```

Comment: How to handle matching brakets `([0-9]|efg)`? Thx :D

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65008426/6824121

You can actually use string-interpolation with raw strings like this:

```dart
final RegExp nameExp = new RegExp(r'^\w{"' '$min' '","' '$max' r'"}$');
```