# regexp to get base64 string of file in imap response

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, base64

I need to parse a imap response to get the base64 string of a file.

The string is something like that:

```
--------------A5B0A8B4F69F8BD959B758D0
Content-Type: application/pdf;
 name="Myfile.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="Myfile.pdf"

JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlL1hPYmplY3QvQ29sb3JT
ZWI0ODRmNDE1ZDE0YmIyZmU2YjAzZDMzNjU+PGU5MDFiZTMzY2FlOTY4ZDM2
NmFmOGNhOTUxNTE0Nzk0Pl0vSW5mbyAyMyAwIFIvU2l6ZSAyND4+CnN0YXJ0
eHJlZgoyMzg2NgolJUVPRgo=

--------------A5B0A8B4F69F8BD959B758D0--
```

I need to get anything after `filename="Myfile.pdf"` (possibly excluding space) and before new line after `=`

I am trying with this regexp without success:

```
(?<=filename="Myfile\.pdf")(.*)(?=\r\n)
```

Actually I am not sure if there are spaces or new lines chars in the base64 string, I do not think.

Comment: Something like `filename="Myfile\.pdf"\s*((?:\n\S.*)+)`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kQ38yy/1). A variation: `filename="Myfile\.pdf"\s*\K\S.*(?:\n\S.*)*`, see [demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/kQ38yy/2).

Comment: What is the tool/programming language you are using?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew dart / flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
filename="Myfile\.pdf"\s*(\S.*(?:\n\S.*)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6bt5Qz/1/). **Details**:

- `filename="Myfile\.pdf"` - a `filename="Myfile.pdf"` string
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `(\S.*(?:\n\S.*)*)` - Group 1:

  - `\S` - a non-whitespace char
  - `.*` - the rest of the line
  - `(?:\n\S.*)*` - 0 or more lines that do not start with whitespace.

Dart/Flutter code to get the first match:

```
final base64str = '--------------A5B0A8B4F69F8BD959B758D0\nContent-Type: application/pdf;\n name="Myfile.pdf"\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\nContent-Disposition: attachment;\n\nfilename="Myfile.pdf"\n\nJVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlL1hPYmplY3QvQ29sb3JT\nZWI0ODRmNDE1ZDE0YmIyZmU2YjAzZDMzNjU+PGU5MDFiZTMzY2FlOTY4ZDM2\nNmFmOGNhOTUxNTE0Nzk0Pl0vSW5mbyAyMyAwIFIvU2l6ZSAyND4+CnN0YXJ0\neHJlZgoyMzg2NgolJUVPRgo=\n\n--------------A5B0A8B4F69F8BD959B758D0--';
final rx = RegExp(r'filename="Myfile\.pdf"\s*(\S.*(?:\n\S.*)*)');
final match = rx.firstMatch(base64str);
if (match != null) {
  print(match.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlL1hPYmplY3QvQ29sb3JT
ZWI0ODRmNDE1ZDE0YmIyZmU2YjAzZDMzNjU+PGU5MDFiZTMzY2FlOTY4ZDM2
NmFmOGNhOTUxNTE0Nzk0Pl0vSW5mbyAyMyAwIFIvU2l6ZSAyND4+CnN0YXJ0
eHJlZgoyMzg2NgolJUVPRgo=
```

Comment: It seems to work. what about if the name of the file is in a variable?

Comment: @GiacomoM You mean you have `final filename = "Myfile.pdf"`? And you build the regex pattern dynamically?

Comment: yes. I am trying to concat regexp with the filename variable but I always get null match

Comment: I solved, really thanks. I have to escape other characters if i concat the regexp with a variable

Comment: @GiacomoM You might use a [regex escape function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50371136/3832970) to escape any arbitrary string. Then, just use `final word = 'Myfile\.pdf'; final rx = RegExp('filename="${escape(word)}"\\s*(\\S.*(?:\n\\S.*)*)');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
(?<=filename="Myfile\.pdf")\s+((?:\S+\s)+\S+)=
```

Please check the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/smmry6/2).

**Update:**

This one includes also the last '='

```
(?<=filename="Myfile\.pdf")\s+((?:\S+\s)+\S+=)
```

Please check demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/smmry6/3).