# Dart: How to force string interpolation on a variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a variable that contains a string with interpolated variables. In the code below, that variable is *template*. When I pass this variable to *generateString* function, I want to apply string interpolation on it because the values which interpolated variables require are available in *generateString* function only.

```
void main() {
  String template = '<p>\${name}</p>';
  var res = generateString(template);
}

generateString(template) {
  var name = 'abc';
  print(template);
  return template;
}
```

The problem is when I am printing and returning template inside generateString fn, I am getting `<p>${name}</p>` instead of `<p>abc</p>`. Is there a way to explicitly tell the dart to so string interpolation?

I am new to Dart. I don't know if it is even possible to achieve or not. Please suggest how do I do this.

Edit: Based on the inputs from other users, I would like to make a clarification about the scenario presented. The value of template variable is not a string literal. I get that from UI as a user input. I have shown it here as a string literal for code simplicity. Also, please consider that name and template are not in the same scope in my scenario.

Comment: your template should be inside "generateString" and then pass a parameter "name". Right now your generateString does absolutely nothing more that return the exact same thing you passed as parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answers so far are wrong.

String interpolation (looking for $, etc) happens only while compiling from the source code to the value in memory.  If **that** string in turn also has a $, it's no longer special.

It's not possible to trigger interpolation past the original compilation step. You can write a templating system that would look for something like `{{name}}` in the value, and replace it with the current value of `name`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining why string interpolating wasn't working in this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the template and the variable in the same scope, it works as expected.

```
// evaluate variable inside ${}
var sport = 'basketball';
String template = 'I like <p>${sport}</p>';
print(template);
```

Comment: No, this isn't working: the template is being processed as a result of compilation.  That's not what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't fully understand your question maybe this will help

```
void main() {
  print(generateString('abc')); //<p>abc</p>
}

generateString(String template) {
  return r"<p>" "$template" r"</p>";
}
```

Comment: What a god, doesn't anderstand the question and still answer it

Answer (score 0):

Walter White here.

You must define the variable `name` as global var, so it can "cook" the string for you